# Conventions for propagators in Feynman diagrams

Tags: conventions, notation, feynman-diagrams, propagator

So far, I picked up the following rules for the propagators:

- Scalars: Dashed
- Fermions: Solid
- Abelian gauge boson: Wavy
- Non-abelian boson: springy
- Ghost: Dotted

This made much sense to me until I saw quite a lot of deviations from this:

- The $\mathrm Z^0$ is sometimes denoted by a dashed line. It is a boson like the other scalars, but it actually is a non-abelian boson.
- The $\mathrm W^\pm$ bosons are often denoted by a wavy line, like the photon. This makes sense as one has electroweak unification. But those bosons can actually interact with themselves as they are non-abelian bosons. Making them a springy line would make more sense.
- When studying pure $\phi^4$ theory, one uses solid lines. This makes sense as this gives nicer looking diagrams. There should not be any confusion if one has only particles of one type in the theory.
- Resonances, usually consisting of multiple particles, are denoted by a double solid line. This makes sense as, say, pions consist of two fermions.

Of course, when one only does QCD, there is no need to reserve a line-style for particles that do not occur. Therefore it seems sensible to use all available line styles to distinguish particles most easily. As I just had a lecture covering the whole standard model, I (still) think of all forces and particles equally often. Reading papers from a given field already ignore some forces or particles and reusing those styles, probably.

Are there any strict global rules regarding the use of different line-styles? If not, are there at least rules common to various fields (hadron physics, …)?

Comment: You missed off gaugino - wavy superimposed on solid

Comment: But you're list looks like the most general set I know

Comment: “Gaugino” sounds like supersymmetry? I did not encountery and SUSY yet, only standard model. But that also makes sense to have as an additional line-style.

Comment: Yes, it's a fermionic partner of a gauge boson, hence the combination of line styles

Comment: To duplicate my wording on a chat discussion of this questions: *There is no Ruling Junta of Physics Notations and Conventions and this stuff varies.* And that's a general rule. Conventions develop, settle, get shaken up, mutate, re-settle, exist in two armed camps for decades at a time, and exhibit all kinds of behavior and divergences. It's simply not safe to think that there is One True Way to do things. And even when there *is* One True Way right *now* there is no guarantee that it will be respected by the 2o year old paper you have to dig up to understand a phase in a paper.

Comment: Chat discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29225208#29225208

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there *is* no universal convention for how lines are drawn, and this question is thus unanswerable. For instance, a scalar (Higgs) line in the Standard Model will usually be dotted, but no one dots a scalar in $\phi^4$ as there is only one type of line there.

Comment: Saying that there is no unique convention also answers the question. You might either turn that into an answer or close the question. I am happy with either. :-)